# Using classes wrong?

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist

so i have very low experience working with classes, but to my project i need to. So i'm doing an app for a bus station, that show the schedule and stuff. So i thought about using classes so its easier to add and remove the timings i want so then after i can send the final to an ArrayList to show on a ListView. But i'm bettin RuntimeExceptions on my class, i don't know if i'm doing it wrong or not, cause i have low experience, i'll show you guys what i have, its a bit extense, cause it's a lot if timers.

```
public class mostraHorario extends Activity {
private ArrayList<String> Coimbra = new ArrayList<String>();

//classe para horario de coimbra
public class horaCoimbra{
    public String hora;
    public int destino;

    public horaCoimbra(String horaIn, int Destino){
        hora = horaIn;
        destino = Destino;
    }

    public void sethora(String horaInicial){
        hora = horaInicial;
    }

    public void setdestino(int refDestino){
        destino = refDestino;
    }
}

horaCoimbra horaC1, horaC2, horaC3, horaC4, horaC5, horaC6, horaC7, horaC8, horaC9, horaC10, horaC11, horaC12, horaC13, horaC14, horaC15, horaC16, horaC17, horaC18, horaC19, horaC20, horaC21, horaC22, horaC23, horaC24, horaC25, horaC26, horaC27, horaC28, horaC29, horaC30, horaC31, horaC32;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostra_horario);

    TextView partida = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.partida);
    TextView destino = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destino);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String Partida = intent.getStringExtra("Partida");
    String Destino = intent.getStringExtra("Destino");
    boolean Sabado = intent.getBooleanExtra("Sabado", true);
    boolean Domingo = intent.getBooleanExtra("Domingo", true);

    buildCoimbra();
    buildArray();

    partida.setText(Partida);
    destino.setText(Destino);

    //Aqui é o horario que vai aparecer
    if (Partida.equals("Coimbra")) {
        ListAdapter horarioAdapter = new costum_adapter(this, Coimbra);
        ListView horarioListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.horario_listView);
        horarioListView.setAdapter(horarioAdapter);
    }
}

public void buildCoimbra(){
    horaC1.sethora("7:15");
    horaC1.destino=9;
    horaC2.sethora("7:50");
    horaC2.destino=4;
    horaC3.sethora("8:25");
    horaC3.destino=9;
    horaC4.sethora("9:00");
    horaC4.destino=7;
    horaC5.sethora("10:00");
    horaC5.destino=7;
    horaC6.sethora("11:15");
    horaC6.destino=7;
    horaC7.sethora("11:25");
    horaC7.destino=3;
    horaC8.sethora("12:10");
    horaC8.destino=9;
    horaC9.sethora("12:25");
    horaC9.destino=3;
    horaC10.sethora("13:10");
    horaC10.destino=9;
    horaC11.sethora("14:05");
    horaC11.destino=7;
    horaC12.sethora("14:05");
    horaC12.destino=3;
    horaC13.sethora("15:15");
    horaC13.destino=9;
    horaC14.sethora("16:00");
    horaC14.destino=9;
    horaC15.sethora("16:15");
    horaC15.destino=7;
    horaC16.sethora("16:40");
    horaC16.destino=4;
    horaC17.sethora("17:10");
    horaC17.destino=6;
    horaC18.sethora("17:10");
    horaC18.destino=4;
    horaC19.sethora("17:15");
    horaC19.destino=5;
    horaC20.sethora("17:20");
    horaC20.destino=9;
    horaC21.sethora("17:40");
    horaC21.destino=9;
    horaC22.sethora("17:45");
    horaC22.destino=4;
    horaC23.sethora("18:00");
    horaC23.destino=6;
    horaC24.sethora("18:00");
    horaC24.destino=3;
    horaC25.sethora("18:15");
    horaC25.destino=6;
    horaC26.sethora("18:30");
    horaC26.destino=9;
    horaC27.sethora("18:45");
    horaC27.destino=3;
    horaC28.sethora("19:10");
    horaC28.destino=7;
    horaC29.sethora("19:10");
    horaC29.destino=3;
    horaC30.sethora("20:15");
    horaC30.destino=6;
    horaC31.sethora("21:45");
    horaC31.destino=6;
    horaC32.sethora("0:05");
    horaC32.destino=6;
}

public void buildArray(){
    Coimbra.add(horaC1.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC2.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC3.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC4.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC5.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC6.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC7.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC8.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC9.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC10.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC11.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC12.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC13.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC14.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC15.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC16.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC17.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC18.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC19.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC20.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC21.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC22.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC23.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC24.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC25.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC26.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC27.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC28.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC29.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC30.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC31.hora);
    Coimbra.add(horaC32.hora);
}
```

}

So here, Coimbra is the ArrayList, where i'm putting the timers to send to the ArrayList. And declare each timer as an object of the class cause i need for each one of them to have the destination atribute, so i can compare with the destitation selected by the user and remove the bus that don't go there.
It's giving me error on the "buildCoimbra();" line, and the sethora lines.

Comment: My Spanish is a little rusty, and Google Translate isn't helping me; what's a "coimbra?" Or is this Portuguese?

Comment: Why are you creating hundreds of variables here rather than using an array list or array. I can see from the text that you that that's an option

Comment: I think that's his question. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Coimbra is a place, a city, from portugal.

Comment: I did it like this cause i want each timers to have 2 atributes

Comment: my question is that if i'm using the classes wrong to give me the runtime exception ?

Comment: An arraylist can contain objects which can have whatever attributes/methods you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

horaC1 = new horaCoimbra("7:15",9);
create objects of horaCoimbra like above

Answer (score 0):

Each time bus times change you have to change, build and install your (updated) program. Your program should instead read the data from a file or database.